# DocuSign 'reassign to someone else' when recipient has 2FA assigned to them

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the DocuSign REST API, and have had no issues using the 'reassign to someone else' feature, when going to sign a document.

However, I have a query relating to how that works when the original recipient was assigned 2FA (SMS or Access Code Authorisation).

I've tested re-assigning to someone else when access code authorisation was assigned to the original recipient and it would appear that the original access code is also re-assigned to the new recipient (I thought that the 2FA would only apply to the original intended recipient).

Lastly, I did the same test again, but using SMS authorization against the original recipient, and it appears as though when the SMS code has been entered, reassigned to someone else, and that new recipient clicks on the email link to sign the document, DocuSign throws an unhelpful error!

[image]

I have raised a ticket with DocuSign asking about the error, but I did wonder what the intended behaviour would be for this SMS scenario, as I was not prompted to enter a mobile number for the new recipient when I 'reassigned to someone else'.

I have also tried this via the DocuSign demo sandbox and experienced exactly the same outcomes for both Access Code & SMS Authorisation scenarios.

**Is there a way to modify this behaviour, so the 'new' recipient does not have 2FA / does not have to enter the access code that was assigned to the original recipient? And has anyone managed to successfully use the Reassign to someone else feature when 2FA was assigned to the original recipient?**

Comment: You found an edge case and I'm not sure what should be the behavior.
One could argue that if the sender wanted the additional security of 2FA, then it's not up to the signer to lower that security by reassigning the envelope to someone else.
On the other hand, someone else can argue that since this person already authenticated with 2FA - then they should not need this once reassigned.
I'll try to get someone here to weigh in by finding the ticket you filed.

Comment: can you provide your ticket number? I can't find your support case without that or your email address...

Comment: Ticket #06371690